# Scaling Images inside a div as browser size changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

First post on stackoverflow. I have found this website extremely useful throughout my past 5 years of studying digital technology at high school. This time everything I find on here wont work, I suspect it's very obvious, just looking for someone to point out my novice mistake.

I have created a website that features large images and lots of JQuery animations, this is a large bulk of my website. When viewed on a 1080p screen it looks as I intended but when i viewed it on a friends smaller resolution screen I realized that I needed to make everything scale. I recoded everything to percentages and used Max-height, max-width on my images to make them scale but my title and link are contained within a div and eve though I have tried max-width,max-height on the images with a set width height on the div it still doesn't seem to work.

TL;DR: I want my title and links to scale as the browser window is resized, as I have already working with the Pukeko and Hills. Any other problems in my code would also be greatly appreciated.

Website: http://pirithepukeko.tumblr.com/

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">

    html {
    overflow: hidden;
    }

    iframe#tumblr_controls {

    top: 0% !important;

    right:0% !important; 

    display:none !important;

    }

    </style>
    <script src=
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(window).load(function() {
    $("#Hill").animate( {top: '-=100%'}, 3000);

    $("#Pukeko").delay(1000).animate( {left: '-=100%'}, 2000);

    $("#P").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#I").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#R").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#I2").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);

    $("#T").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#H").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#E").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);

    $("#P2").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#U").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#K").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#E2").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#K2").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#0").delay(2000).fadeIn(3000);
    $("#BuyButton").delay(4000).fadeIn(4000);
    $("#ExampleButton").delay(4000).fadeIn(4000);

    });
    </script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <img id="bg" src="http://i.imgur.com/wpAxcsD.png" style=
    "position:fixed; top: 0; left: 0; min-width:100%; min-height: 100%;">
    <div id="header" style=
    "position:absolute; z-index: 2; Left:12%; Top:20%; max-width:50%; max-Height:20%;">
    <img id="P" src="http://i.imgur.com/VAjsWaY.png" style=
    "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        <img id="I" src="http://i.imgur.com/tx3QKsv.png" style=
        "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        <img id="R" src="http://i.imgur.com/2z85VMR.png" style=
        "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        <img id="I2" src="http://i.imgur.com/tx3QKsv.png" style=
        "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <img id="T" src=
        "http://i.imgur.com/MQOOrTY.png" style=
        "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        <img id="H" src="http://i.imgur.com/A7RunYJ.png" style=
        "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        <img id="E" src="http://i.imgur.com/2M9Fyg9.png" style=
        "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        <p>
            <img id="P2" src="http://i.imgur.com/VAjsWaY.png" style=
            "z-index: 2; display:none;max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
            <img id="U" src="http://i.imgur.com/7ukLJsL.png" style=
            "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
            <img id="K" src="http://i.imgur.com/agxDLLs.png" style=
            "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
            <img id="E2" src="http://i.imgur.com/2M9Fyg9.png" style=
            "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
            <img id="K2" src="http://i.imgur.com/agxDLLs.png" style=
            "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;"><img>
            <img id="0" src="http://i.imgur.com/WRT7FYQ.png" style=
            "z-index: 2; display:none; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;">
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.pirithepukeko.tumblr.com/Buy"><img id=
            "BuyButton" src="http://i.imgur.com/Q4eqkdm.png" style=
            "display:none; z-index: 2; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; min-width: 5%; min-height: 5%;"></a>
        </p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
            <a href="http://www.pirithepukeko.tumblr.com/example"><img id=
            "ExampleButton" src="http://i.imgur.com/CpinwiT.png" style=
            "display:none; z-index: 2; max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; min-width: 5%; min-height: 5%;"></a>
        </p><br>
    </div>
    <div id="stuff" style=" z-index: 1; Left:0%; Top:0%;">
        <img id="Hill" src="http://i.imgur.com/r3gkAkv.png" style=
        "position:fixed; Left:0%; TOP:100%; z-index: 1; max-width: 100%; max-height: 110%; min-width: 50%; min-height: 50%;">
        <img id="Pukeko" src="http://i.imgur.com/cO8u6M6.png" style=
        "position:fixed; TOP:0%; LEFT:100%; max-width:100%; max-height:110%; z-index: 1;">
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding max and min widths won't solve your problem since there is no guarantee that those percentages will act same in all the device sizes. Either you should look into [css media queries](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) or more reliable and professional way to solve this would be to use a framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)